# java and jboss7 j_security_check Login Successfull but with Problems

Tags: java, security, jsf, jboss7.x, jaas

I created Custom Database Server Login Module and i created a Form with j_security_check it works successfully but the problems are:

1. Sometime jboss return error code 408 : **When log in successful it doesn't redirect to the page defined in **form-login-page*** tag in web.xml.* (*408: Request Timeout: The client did not produce a request within the time that the server was prepared to wait. The client MAY repeat the request without modifications at any later time.*)
2. Sometime jboss returns error code 400 (*Bad Request: The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.*).
3. The page which is defined to be authorized to the role x. i run it and i can view it successfully without log in.
4. Unfortunately i don't have a particular scenario for the problems above.

this is the security-cosntraint tag in web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>InstitutionRole</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/jsfs/services/ManageData.jsf</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Institution_delegate</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/index.jsf</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/jsfs/errors/loginError.jsf</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>

</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description>Institution Delegate Role</description>
    <role-name>Institution_delegate</role-name>
</security-role>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

pleas help .... any ideas ????

Comment: Both errors 408 and 400 are related to client requests being sent. You do need a reproducible test case before going further - I'd start out by sniffing HTTP traffic so you would at least get the logs of the problem when it happens. The third problem seems separate, it doesn't sound like your configuration is done right.

Comment: i can identify the problem is in configuration in web.xml in the security-constraint section ... my question is what is the url mapping of jsf pages ?

Comment: please add your existing configuration in the question.

Comment: i put the web.xml in the question....

Comment: i figured out the problem and i have the solution but i have problem with my reputations in my profile

Comment: @abutaha9 A problem that prevents you from posting an answer? What's the issue?

Comment: The Problem because i am new in Stackoverflow and i must reach number of badges and reputations to answer quikly...i well post the answer when the lock release.

Answer (score 0):

I have the Answer of this Problem it was in the Deployment Descriptor file web.xml...

> In the Security Constraint the page url in "form-login-page" tag **is the Login page url** not **"the page after successful log in"** so when you are calling the page1.jsf and you haven't logged in before the login.jsf well lunched up automatically .

so

if you have a constraint on Page : /page1.jsf for role : x

```
 <security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>x</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/page1.jsf</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>x</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
```

```
<security-role>
    <description>x Role</description>
    <role-name>x</role-name>
</security-role>
```

you must put

```
<login-config>
<auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
<form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login.jsf</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/jsfs/errors/loginError.jsf</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
```

I Hope this Solution well help you ....